# Is there $n \geq 2$ such that $1^1 + 2^2 + \dots + n^n$ is a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

Define $S_n = 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + \dots + (n - 1)^{n - 1} + n^n$. It is clear that $S_1 = 1^1 = 1$ is a perfect square. However, I have found no others so far.

**Question**: Does there exist $n \geq 2$ such that $S_n$ is a perfect square?

I have checked via computer that there are no solutions for $2 \leq n \leq 3000$. Analysis modulo $3$ reveals that $$n \equiv 2,3,5,6,10,13 \pmod{18} \Rightarrow S_n \equiv 2 \pmod{3},$$ and hence $S_n$ is not a perfect square for these values of $n$. I imagine one could do similar analysis using other moduli, but it does not seem to eliminate many values of $n$.

I currently do not have a great reason for believing that the answer to the question is no, but I also have no idea how, aside from burning my CPU, to show that the answer could be yes. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

(*I even tried searching for perfect powers in general, and have so far only found $$S_3 = 2^5$$ as an example.*)

**Edit 1**: The analysis done modulo 3 can be replicated for other moduli, and this can actually be useful if you are trying to search for solutions by computer. I make a useful conjecture:

*Conjecture:* The residues of $S_n$ modulo an odd prime $p$ are periodic (over consecutive integers $n$) with period $p^2(p - 1)$. Furthermore, there are exactly $p(p - 1)^2/2$ residues of $n$ modulo $p^2(p - 1)$ which imply $S_n$ to not be congruent to a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Thus, we can identify, based on the residue of $n$ modulo $p^2(p - 1)$, whether $S_n$ is congruent to a quadratic residue modulo $p$. This is beneficial since I imagine computing $n$ mod $p^2(p - 1)$ is faster than checking whether $S_n$ is a perfect square.

With this "result" applied to only the first six odd primes $3,5,7,11,13,17$ (I have verified the conjecture is true for these), it appears we already can say that for about $96.4 \%$ of the natural numbers, $S_n$ is not a perfect square. You could probably show this rigorously via the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but whatever. (And of course, I imagine the more primes you use, the better the results, but at some point too many modulus operations becomes a burden.)

Comment: What is the source of this problem? This [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815067/diophantine-equation-containing-sum-s-n-11223344) appeared yesterday.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that is where this problem came from.

Comment: Ah.  Well, I don't see a useful algebraic factoring.  For a particular $n$ you can look at primes $p$ such that $p-1\,|\,n$  which simplifies the sum enormously.  Otherwise, it looks hard to attack.

Comment: Let $p$ be any prime greater than $n$.  Fermat's Little Theorem forces the $n$th partial sum to be $\equiv n(n+1)/2$ mod $p$.  Only the "triangular squares" $1^2, 6^2, 35^2,...$ seem to have a chance so we need this to work for $n \in \{1, 8, 49,...\}$.

Comment: No further perfect power upto $n=87\ 000$

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001923